# How to rollback to the last build with cruisecontrol?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I just finished my cc.net configuration for getting the code from svn, building it and then copying the web site in our servers.

Now we have an other requirement : we want to be able to roll back to one of the previous successful build (most of the time the one before the last).

We are deploying an asp.net web site so there is no assembly versioning here.

I searched here and on google but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: CruiseControl.Net can be configured to store previous builds results/artifacts (e.g. last 50), have you tried this? Although you won't get automatic rollback this way.

Comment: I don't really want automatic rollback, because we'll do the rollback only if some there is some business trouble with our deployment (like unable to book or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is take back ups of the project builds. So after successful build of the project and before copying to server take a backup of the build with an appropriate name.

So if we want to revert you can use the back up file saved. Usually we follow that method. But it requires manually copying the files.

I don't think there is any other rollback methods in cruise control .net.

You can add a publisher block to copy files. To take backup just check the code

```
<publishers>

    <buildpublisher>
      <sourceDir>Source Path</sourceDir>
      <publishDir>Backup path</publishDir>
      <alwaysPublish>false</alwaysPublish>
      <useLabelSubDirectory>true</useLabelSubDirectory>
      <cleanUpValue>10</cleanUpValue>
      <cleanUpMethod>KeepLastXBuilds</cleanUpMethod>
    </buildpublisher>
</publisher>
```

it will take `10` backups according to clean up value

Comment: perfect, I'll just create an other project  that'll do the roll back (a batch 'll wait the revision number in parameter)

Comment: @remi: its really great idea. We didn't think about it, instead we are just manually taking the back up files.